# Pine script to python Conversion for Hull Butterfly Oscillator

Tags: python, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to convert pinescript to python for Hull Butterfly Oscillator made by LuxAlgo
Pinescript code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Hull Butterfly Oscillator [LuxAlgo]", "Hull Butterfly Oscillator [LuxAlgo]")
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Settings
//----------------------------------------------------a-------------------------{
length = input(14)

mult = input(2., 'Levels Multiplier')

src = input(close)

//Style
bull_css_0 = input.color(color.new(#0cb51a, 50), 'Bullish Gradient'
  , inline = 'inline0'
  , group = 'Style')

bull_css_1 = input.color(#0cb51a, ''
  , inline = 'inline0'
  , group = 'Style')

bear_css_0 = input.color(color.new(#ff1100, 50), 'Bearish Gradient'
  , inline = 'inline1'
  , group = 'Style')

bear_css_1 = input.color(#ff1100, ''
  , inline = 'inline1'
  , group = 'Style')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Normalization variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var short_len = int(length / 2)
var hull_len = int(math.sqrt(length))

var den1 = short_len * (short_len + 1) / 2
var den2 = length * (length + 1) / 2
var den3 = hull_len * (hull_len + 1) / 2

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Hull coefficients
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var lcwa_coeffs = array.new_float(hull_len, 0)
var hull_coeffs = array.new_float(0)

if barstate.isfirst
    //Linearly combined WMA coeffs
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum1 = math.max(short_len - i, 0)
        sum2 = length - i
    
        array.unshift(lcwa_coeffs, 2 * (sum1 / den1) - (sum2 / den2))
    
    //Zero padding of linearly combined WMA coeffs
    for i = 0 to hull_len-2
        array.unshift(lcwa_coeffs, 0)
    
    //WMA convolution of linearly combined WMA coeffs
    for i = hull_len to array.size(lcwa_coeffs)-1
        sum3 = 0.
        for j = i-hull_len to i-1
            sum3 += array.get(lcwa_coeffs, j) * (i - j)
        
        array.unshift(hull_coeffs, sum3 / den3)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Hull squeeze oscillator
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var os  = 0
var len = array.size(hull_coeffs)-1
hma     = 0.
inv_hma = 0.

for i = 0 to len
    hma += src[i] * array.get(hull_coeffs, i)
    inv_hma += src[len-i] * array.get(hull_coeffs, i)
    
hso = hma - inv_hma

cmean = ta.cum(math.abs(hso)) / bar_index * mult

os := ta.cross(hso, cmean) or ta.cross(hso, -cmean) ? 0
  : hso < hso[1] and hso > cmean ? -1
  : hso > hso[1] and hso < -cmean ? 1
  : os

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plot
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Colors
css0 = color.from_gradient(hso, 0, cmean, bull_css_0, bull_css_1)
css1 = color.from_gradient(hso, -cmean, 0, bear_css_1, bear_css_0)
css = hso > 0 ? css0 : css1

//Oscillator line/histogram
plot(hso, 'Hull Butterfly', css
  , style = plot.style_histogram)

plot(hso, 'Hull Butterfly', chart.fg_color)

//Dots
plot(os > os[1] and os == 1 ? hso : na, 'Bullish Dot'
  , bull_css_1
  , 2
  , plot.style_circles)
  
plot(os < os[1] and os == -1 ? hso : na, 'Bearish Dot'
  , bear_css_1
  , 2
  , plot.style_circles)


//Levels
plot(cmean, color = color.gray, editable = false)

plot(cmean / 2, color = color.gray, editable = false)

plot(-cmean / 2, color = color.gray, editable = false)

plot(-cmean, color = color.gray, editable = false)
```

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd


# Settings
length = 14
mult = 2.0
# Load your data and parameters
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
close_prices = data['Close']
src = close_prices

# Style
bull_css_0 = (15, 192, 33, 50)
bull_css_1 = (15, 192, 33, 100)
bear_css_0 = (255, 17, 0, 50)
bear_css_1 = (255, 17, 0, 100)

# Normalization variables
short_len = length // 2
hull_len = int(math.sqrt(length))
den1 = short_len * (short_len + 1) // 2
den2 = length * (length + 1) // 2
den3 = hull_len * (hull_len + 1) // 2

# Hull coefficients
lcwa_coeffs = np.zeros(hull_len)
hull_coeffs = []

# Linearly combined WMA coeffs
for i in range(length):
    sum1 = max(short_len - i, 0)
    sum2 = length - i
    lcwa_coeffs = np.insert(lcwa_coeffs, 0, 2 * (sum1 / den1) - (sum2 / den2))

# Zero padding of linearly combined WMA coeffs
for _ in range(hull_len - 1):
    lcwa_coeffs = np.insert(lcwa_coeffs, 0, 0)

# WMA convolution of linearly combined WMA coeffs
for i in range(hull_len, len(lcwa_coeffs)):
    sum3 = 0.0
    for j in range(i - hull_len, i):
        sum3 += lcwa_coeffs[j] * (i - j)
    hull_coeffs.insert(0, sum3 / den3)

# Print the calculated Hull coefficients
print("Hull Coefficients:", hull_coeffs)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Hull squeeze oscillator
os = 0
len_coeffs = len(hull_coeffs) - 1
hma = 0
inv_hma = 0

for i in range(len_coeffs + 1):
    hma += src[i] * hull_coeffs[i]
    inv_hma += src[len_coeffs - i] * hull_coeffs[i]

hso = hma - inv_hma

cmean = np.cumsum(np.abs(hso)) / np.arange(1, len(src) + 1) * mult

if (hso > cmean).any() or (hso < -cmean).any():
    os = 0
elif hso < hso[1] and hso > cmean:
    os = -1
elif hso > hso[1] and hso < -cmean:
    os = 1

# Print or visualize the results as needed
print("Hull Butterfly Oscillator:", hso)
print("OS:", os)



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Colors
bull_css_0 = 'green'
bull_css_1 = 'lime'
bear_css_0 = 'red'
bear_css_1 = 'maroon'
cmean_color = 'gray'

css0 = np.where(hso > 0, bull_css_0, bull_css_1)
css1 = np.where(hso > 0, bear_css_1, bear_css_0)
css = np.where(hso > 0, css0, css1)

# Create plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(np.arange(len(hso)), hso, color=css)
ax.plot(hso, color='black')

os = np.zeros_like(hso)
bullish_dots = np.where((os > os[1]) & (os == 1), hso, np.nan)
bearish_dots = np.where((os < os[1]) & (os == -1), hso, np.nan)

ax.plot(bullish_dots, 'o', color=bull_css_1, markersize=2)
ax.plot(bearish_dots, 'o', color=bear_css_1, markersize=2)

levels = [cmean, cmean / 2, -cmean / 2, -cmean]

for level in levels:
    ax.axhline(y=level, color=cmean_color, linestyle='dashed')

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ax.bar(np.arange(len(hso)), hso, color=css)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

I tried to create a list with just one element because hso is just a float number, but it did not work. Regardless of this error I believe something is wrong with my code. Can you please help?